# @Retryable with exceptionExpression does not set any #root object neither variables

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-retry

I'm using Spring Retry 1.2.4 with `@Retryable` annotation in a library dependency of a SpringBatch.

In the `exceptionExpression` attribute I specify an expression `#root.status.is5xxServerError()` of a custom exception for which I mention the class in the `include` attribute.

But it leads to an error with the following message :

> org.springframework.retry.RetryException: Non-skippable exception in recoverer while processing; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1001E: Type conversion problem, cannot convert from java.lang.String to java.lang.Boolean

What I find strange is that the batch `faultTolerant` configuration seems to be in conflict with the library configuration, if I have a look at the "Non-skippable exception in recoverer while processing" into the final message.

Also while debugging in SpEL expression evaluation I notice no root object neither any variables are set in the EvaluationContext though it is trying to resolve `#root.status.is5xxServerError()`. Perhaps it is linked with the observation above.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression support in those annotation is very basic.

I recently opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/issues/184) to add improvements (runtime evaluation etc).

Comment: are you sure this is the only way?
could you give an example please?

Comment: An example of what? As I said, the expression is currently only evaluated once, during initialization; the functionality you want needs changes to the framework.

Comment: Ha sorry, misunderstood...
Thank you anyway